# Gridview alterar Row para ReadOnly

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Como é que posso alterar row de uma `GridView` para readonly?
Necessito de através de valores de uma das celulas permitir ou não a edição da linha de `GridView`.

Comment: Dê mais detalhes, por favor. Como por exemplo: O que você tem nas linhas da GridView; que tipo de campo está querendo verificar para permitir ou não a edição. Em que momento está querendo fazer essa verificação. Com mais informações você conseguirá alcançar um público alvo maior para poder lhe ajudar, ao invés de ficar esperando por alguém que vai ler essas simples palavras e entender logo de cara o que você quer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, se você encontrar um valor em alguma das `Cells`
voce quer que sua linha se torne read only, então segue algo que tive em mente:

VB:

```
 For RCnt As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    If DataGridView1.Rows(RCnt).Cells("SpecificCell").Value = "Something" Then
    DataGridView.Rows(RCnt).ReadOnly = True
    End If
    Next
```

C#

```
for (int RCnt = 0; RCnt <= DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; RCnt++) 
{
    if (DataGridView1.Rows(RCnt).Cells("SpecificCell").Value == "Something") 
    {
        DataGridView.Rows(RCnt).ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```